# Sum two tables value and show value if one column is null

Tags: sql

I have two table's column and i want to sum both values but my one column is null and when i run below query its showing all null.

```
SELECT
    Product.ProductID, 
    Product.ProductName, 
    (select round(sum(quantity),18, 2)from [ProductPur] where [ProductPur].[ProductID] = product.ProductID) AS Purchased_quantity,
    (select round(sum(quantity),18 ,2)from [PGDN] where [PGDN].[ProductID] = product.ProductID)+(select round(sum(quantity),18 ,2)from [returnnonreturndetails] where [returnnonreturndetails].[ProductID] = product.ProductID) AS Sold_quantity,
     (select round(sum(quantity),18 ,2)from [ProductPur] where [ProductPur].[ProductID] = product.ProductID) - (select round(sum(quantity),18, 2)from [PGDN] where [PGDN].[ProductID] = product.ProductID) AS Stock
FROM Product
ORDER BY Product.ProductName;
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic SQL solution uses `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT p.ProductID, p.ProductName, 
       (select round(sum(quantity),18, 2) from ProductPur pp where pp.[ProductID] = p.ProductID) AS Purchased_quantity,
       (COALESCE( (select round(sum(quantity), 18, 2) from [PGDN] pg where pg.[ProductID] = p.ProductID), 0) +
        COALESCE( (select round(sum(quantity), 18, 2) from returnnonreturndetails rd where rd.[ProductID] = p.ProductID), 0)
       ) AS Sold_quantity,
       (COALESCE( (select round(sum(quantity), 18, 2) from ProductPur pp where pp.[ProductID] = p.ProductID), 0) -
        COALESCE( (select round(sum(quantity), 18, 2) from [PGDN] pg where pg.[ProductID] = p.ProductID), 0)
       ) AS Stock
FROM Product p
ORDER BY p.ProductName;
```

In SQL Server, `ISNULL()` is a better choice, for performance reasons.

Answer (score 1):

you need to check value with `isnull` function i.e. `isnull(quantity,0)`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your DBMS, you can have to use `IFNULL()` (MySQL), `ISNULL()` (SQL Server, MS Access) or `NVL()` (Oracle). You can also use `COALESCE()`, which would be the generic solution.

All of those functions are used the same:

```
ISNULL($statement,$value_if_statement_is_null)
```

For example

```
select round(sum(isnull(quantity,0)),18, 2)
from [ProductPur]
where [ProductPur].[ProductID] = product.ProductID)
```